# Объединение нескольких файловых массивов в один (Java)

Tags: java, массивы, файлы, arraylist

У меня есть 10 файлов в директории A, 5 файлов в директории B и 2 файла в директории C.

`FileArray1 = ["src/dirA/file_1", "src/dirA/file_2", "src/dirA/file_3", "src/dirA/file_4", "src/dirA/file_5", "src/dirA/file_6", "src/dirA/file_7", "src/dirA/file_8", "src/dirA/file_9", "src/dirA/file_10"]`

`FileArray2 = ["src/dirB/file_11", "src/dirB/file_12", "src/dirB/file_13", "src/dirB/file_14", "src/dirB/file_15"]`

`FileArray3 = ["src/dirC/file_16", "src/dirC/file_17"]`

Как мне их объединить в один массив `files[]`?

Comment: Создать ArrayList (так как изначально неизвестно суммарное колличество элементов массива). Потом заходить в каждый файл по очереди (путь к каждому файлу, насколько я понял, у вас известен и лежит в массиве), вычитывать каждый файл сканнером. Потом парсить его методом split() - в зависимости от того, через какой разделитель у вас разделены в файлах элементы массива. Каждый элемент добавлять в ArrayList(), который в конце преобразовать в массив. Быстрого решения тут нет. Придется поэтапно выполнять каждую операцию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если задача состоит в том, чтобы объединить несколько массивов объектов в один, проще всего воспользоваться Stream API:

```java
public static<T> T[] join(IntFunction<T[]> generator, T[] ... arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray(generator);
}
```

Пример (для массивов строк):

```java
String[] a1 = {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"};
String[] a2 = {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"};
String[] a3 = {"c1", "c2"};

String[] merged = join(String[]::new, a1, a2, a3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged));
```

```
[a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, c1, c2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Пусть у вас есть три массива строк:

```java
String[] array1 = ...
String[] array2 = ...
String[] array3 = ...
```

Создайте массив `output` суммарного размера:

```java
String[] output = new String[array1.length + array2.length + array3.length];
```

Последовательно скопируйте содержимое каждого массива в массив `output` с помощью вызова [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-):

```java
int position = 0;
System.arraycopy(array1, 0, output, position, array1.length);
position += array1.length;
System.arraycopy(array2, 0, output, position, array2.length);
position += array2.length;
System.arraycopy(array3, 0, output, position, array3.length);
```